# LGPL static linking

Tags: lgpl, linked-libraries

I know there are already many other questions asked about LGPL requirements, but none of those did match my case

I want to distribute a free application which uses a LGPL-licensed library (Qt)

Assuming I linked statically, do I have to supply the sources with the application? If yes, is a link to a repository (GitHub) enough?
And where should I mention the application is LGPL-licensed? Is a simple "About" window with the default snippet enough? Or do I have absolutely to include a LICENSE file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming I linked statically, do I have to supply the sources with the application?

Yes.

> If yes, is a link to a repository (GitHub) enough?

It may be if this is the LGPL 3 and the link is provided at the same time as the the application is downloaded and the links point to the exact version of the corresponding source code for your app and QT and that it is under your control. Otherwise it may not be enough.

> And where should I mention the application is LGPL-licensed? Is a simple "About" window with the default snippet enough?  Or do I have absolutely to include a LICENSE file?

Yes, you have to include the license file.

Comment: For completeness, note that providing object code is also acceptable. But your answer is a quite good approximation.